# возврат вверх по DOM в цикле функции

Tags: javascript, html

есть такой код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".portfolio-item").each(function(i) {
        $(this).find("a").attr("href", "#portfolioModal_" + i);
        $(this).find(".portfolio-modal").attr("id", "portfolioModal_" + i )
    });

});
```

Он присваивает `id` ссылкам и модальному окну, но дело в том, что модалка находится не в текущем `(".portfolio-item")`, а в теле документа, то есть `this` тут не срабатывает.

Так вот вопрос: как сделать, что бы вернуться вверх по `DOM`, дабы указать на присваивание `id` модальному окну.

Comment: приведи пример разметки

Answer (score 0):

При использовании jQuery вы можете воспользоваться методами .parent() и .closest() 
Пример:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".portfolio-item").each(function(i, el) {
    let $el = $(el);

    $el.find("a").attr("href", "#portfolioModal_" + i);
    $el.find(".portfolio-modal").attr("id", "portfolioModal_" + i);

    $el.parent(); //будет родитель $el
    $el.closest('.portfilio_wrapper'); //первый родитель с классом .portfolio_wrapper
  });
});
```

Также не рекомендую использовать this как указатель на элемент, возможно это вкусовщина, но тем не менее данный подход считается моветоном.